# Vim - custom syntax - how to match second word

Tags: t-sql, vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to make a custom syntax highlighting for Sybase T-SQL and I'm stuck when I try to match table name in the following line:

```
UPDATE myTableName
```

I've tried:

```
syn match tsqlUpdateTableName "\w\+" contained
syn match tsqlUpdateLine "update.*" nextgroup=tsqlUpdateTableName

hi tsqlUpdateTableName guifg=white guibg=red
```

But it does not match myTableName
I would appreciate any help.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `nextgroup` only matches *after* the current group's match.

You can fix this by excluding the table name in the line match, either by dropping the `.*` or, as I've done here, by asserting the following table name but ending the match with `\ze`:

```
syn match tsqlUpdateTableName "\w\+" contained
syn match tsqlUpdateLine "update \ze\w\+" nextgroup=tsqlUpdateTableName
```

Alternatively, you can include the table name in the line match and use `contains=` instead:

```
syn match tsqlUpdateTableName "update \zs\w\+" contained
syn match tsqlUpdateLine "update \w\+" contains=tsqlUpdateTableName
```

---

PS: You should probably tighten your patterns to entire-word matches, e.g. `"\<update\>`; otherwise, it may mistakenly match inside words like `catchupdate`.

Comment: Thanks Ingo for explaining, it works as intended! Have a nice day.